# left join does not return all rows

Tags: android, sqlite, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables, `property_master` and `tanant_master`, and fields are as below:

property_master --> p_id,pname

tanant_master -->t_id,p_id,t_name;

I have 3 properties inside `property_master` like PRO1,PRO2,PRO3, and 2 tenants in `tanant_master` like T1,T2.

T1 is assigned to PRO1 and T2 assigned to PRO2, there are not any tenants in PRO3 so now I want to find total number of tenants in all properties so my query is as below:

```
SELECT p.p_id AS code, t.p_name AS Property, count( p.t_id ) AS total_count
FROM tanant_master p
LEFT JOIN property_master t ON t.p_id = p.p_id
GROUP BY p.p_id
```

When I run this query it will give only 2 property values like PRO1 and PRO2, but I also want count for PRO3 as 0. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A left join returns all rows from the table on its left side.
In this case, this is the `tanant_master` table, so you get all tenants.

To get all properties, use that table on the left side:

```
SELECT p_id AS code,
       p_name AS Property,
       COUNT(t_id) AS total_count
FROM property_master
LEFT JOIN tanant_master USING (p_id)
GROUP BY p_id
```